# Google script to send email draft and mark email sent in sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

This is my first post and I am new to google scripting and a novice Javascript-er. I am trying to work out the kinks for our real estate CRM.  What I am trying to do is send our Happy Birthday draft email (labeled 'Happy-Birthday') from our company to each of our client's on their respective birthdays.  I have their birthdays in Column C and Column D has a formula to test whether or not today is their birthday (TRUE/FALSE). I will have the below script run everyday. The script is working overall and successfully sends the email to their email address in Column B with the subject in Column A; however, I CANNOT figure out how to automatically enter a notification (with a date) in Column E for each birthday email that is sent.

Here is my google sheet for reference: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iiY-3tZI1rGsND-3PhoN_g8hPPEZ5dlXQ4zOyyla1Tk/edit?usp=sharing

Here is my code that is not currently work insofar as the email notification is concerned:

```
function sendBirthdayEmails() {

  var threads = GmailApp.search('in:draft label:Happy-Birthday');

  if(threads.length == 0){
    MailApp.sendEmail("sam@masonrealestate.net", "Happy Birthday email ERROR!!", "There was an error sending the automatic Mason Real Estate Happy Birthday Email. No Draft was found with the label 'Happy-Birthday'. ERROR No. 1");
    return;
  }

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1iiY-3tZI1rGsND-3PhoN_g8hPPEZ5dlXQ4zOyyla1Tk");  //*******NEED TO UPDATE FOR CRM - Data Sheet********* 
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Birthday Emails')

  var range = sheet.getRange("J1"); 
  var dateString = new Date().toString();
  range.setValue(dateString);   // this makes all formulas recalculate

  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 1000;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:E1000
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();   

  var emailSentNotification = "Email Sent" & dateString;

  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    if( row[3] == true) {
      var emailAddress = row[1];  // Second column for email addresses
      var subject = row[0];       // First Column

      sheet.getRange(i+2,5).setValue(emailSentNotification);

      try {
        // finds the Happy Birthday draft email and sends it to the Client's email address and the subject includes their name.  
        for(var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++){
            var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
            for(var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++){
              var mssg = messages[j];
              if(mssg.isDraft()){
                mssg.forward(emailAddress, {
                  // cc: "",
                  bcc: "sam@masonrealestate.net",
                  subject: subject,
                  name: "Mason Real Estate Company"
                });
              }
            }
          //threads[i].removeLabel(labelHappy-Birthday);
        }

      } catch(errorDetails) {
        MailApp.sendEmail("sam@masonrealestate.net", "Happy Birthday email ERROR!!", "There was an error sending the automatic Mason Real Estate Happy Birthday Email. ERROR No. 2");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: any particular why are you creating draft  & then sending mails and not directly sent the mail?

Comment: Through my own research, it looked like creating and emailing a draft would be the easiest solution in order to send a standard Happy Birthday email with formatted images/text/etc.  If the email was text only, then it would've been easier to send the email via the script. However, I'm open to ideas...